# Unable to boot Ubuntu, installed after Windows on the same SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

Title. Once it asks me to remove installation medium and press enter, it will just boot to Windows.
No, it's not a boot order issue, i've put anything windows related to the latest position...
I've tried to reinstall multiple times, i've changed the pendrive and even the software used to flash them (first rufus, then balenaetcher).
I've tried bootrepair and use it to reinstall grub.
From gparted, it shows the 25gb partition being ext4 with 8gb used and it shows "reinstall ubuntu" when booting the ubuntu pendrive.
I think the system is definetely there, but i can't boot it.

The laptop is a Maibook x658, or Eluktronics 16" Prometheus XVI. Quanta chassis laptop with a 5900hx processor and 3060 130w rtx graphics card.
I've also tried to disable secureboot... other than that, the BIOS is very basic.
I don't know what else to try.

OS ver is Ubuntu 21.10 non LTS

Comment: You're telling us that you put Windows *last* in boot priority, but you say nothing about Ubuntu's place in boot priority. Did you put it *first*? Is it even an option? If there's no option then it doesn't sound like you actually installed Ubuntu correctly. Here's what you should troubleshoot: Maybe you should delete the Ubuntu partition and try again. Are you using the "Install alongside Windows" option & default installation options? Are you booting the USB in the same mode as your Windows installation (usually UEFI)? Are you sure your installation media is valid and passes integrity checks?

Comment: Also, 25GB is the **bare minimum** recommended for Ubuntu Desktop. It would be wise to allocate more space than the minimum if you can afford it.

Comment: Hi, uefi options are the following: 1.Others 2. PCIE SSD 3. USB DEVICE 4. Others: Network Boot-IPV4 5. Windows boot manager 6. PCIE SSD: Windows boot manager. I have reinstalled 5 times already from two different pendrives, made with two different softwares. The first time i've tried with 64 gb size, i don't need that much space because i only need it to study with hackthebox.com and try it, if i need more i will repartition the SSD. I am using the default options but also tried more settings to make a partition manually and install from there. No use.

Comment: Yes i am booting the USB in the same mode... i've manually selected GPT UEFI from rufus, i assume balenaetcher is doing the same even without selecting...

Comment: How you boot flash drive installer, is then how it installs. Most can be booted in UEFI or old BIOS mode, so always choose UEFI boot option. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: What you choose in Rufus is not the same thing. You are choosing the partition scheme for the USB drive. You need to choose UEFI in boot options (assuming Windows is a UEFI install). Etcher creates installation media that can be booted UEFI or MBR/legacy. If you don't know how to boot UEFI media with your motherboard- read your motherboard's documentation.